# What polyhedron has the highest surface area to price ratio for tea bags?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, optimization, polytopes

I recently purchased tea where the tea bags were oddly tetrahedron-shaped rather than the common square tea bag shape. My girlfriend told me that the tetrahedron shape maximizes surface area, compared to the common type of bag. I responded why not make the tea bags a shape with a lot of convexities and concavities, like a 3D star or something, since such a shape would have even more surface area. She responded that the cost to produce such a complicated shape would likely be a lot higher, and so the tetrahedron must be some optimal polyhedron that maximizes the surface area to cost ratio.

Let's say for a polyhedron:

1. an edge costs $1 (since an edge implies a worker having to stitch those sides of the tea bag material together)
2. The polyhedron must be able to fit inside a sphere with radius 1 centimeter. (So we cannot construct a tetrahedron with huge faces and a small volume)
3. There can only be finite vertices, edges, and faces.

I want to emphasize that volume doesn't really matter. We just need a few chopped tea leaves to make a cup of tea. But we need those chopped leaves maximally distributed to quicken the dissolving process.

These constraints were chosen for simplicity's sake.

My question is, what polyhedron, if any, meets those 3 constraints and maximizes the surface area to cost ratio?

Comment: So instead of cost, it's the number of edges in your interpretation, right? The length of them doesn't matter

Comment: Using a sphere (i.e. no edges) you get the maximum surface and a division by $0$! Ahaha

Comment: @Gabrielek I did say polyhedron only. ;) Also spheres minimize surface area, not maximize. A 3D koch snowflake for example has infinite surface area and finite volume.

Comment: @YuriyS Yes, you are correct. Edge length does not matter. Faces and edges do not have to share the same area/length.

Comment: @YuriyS I edited the question so that the polyhedron must be able to fit inside a sphere with radius 1cm. This will prevent you from constructing a tetrahedron with huge faces, but small volume.

Comment: Don't forget that storage volume matters just as much as production cost. The teabags need to fit together into a relatively small rectangular box. Storage and transportation costs are important. Your previous comment kind of addresses this

Comment: @YuriyS haha true :) however, the tea bags I purchased seem to made of bendable mesh. We can just stuff a bunch into a box freely, and they will simply expand to their true shape when placed in water!

Comment: With the new constraint I don't believe there's anything better than a tetrahedron, although fitting in the same sphere means that different shapes will have different volumes, so I'm not sure it makes sense

Comment: @YuriyS I do see your point. Do you have a better constraint in mind for this question?

Comment: I think if you are interested in mathematics, you should focus on that. In truth, I doubt that any tea packaging company worries that much about the precise shape. And neither do the customers. Tetrahedrons truly work better than ordinary bags, but what's the point of trying further improvement? It's not like it will make tea taste better or anything :P

Comment: @YuriyS In truth, I **only** care about the mathematics, and very little about the other aspects of the problem. ;) There is no upper bound to polyhedra that maximize surface area when volume is held constant, so this is kind of an interesting optimization problem where maximizing surface area is kinda possible.

Comment: The square teabag is not a polyhedron. The only way you can fit the tea in is by stretching the squares. So I would challenge your girlfriends claims (or maybe not if you want to remain friends $\ddot{\smile}$).

Comment: @RobArthan Hah, well I suppose the square tea bag shape is not in our feasibility set. :) Or you can consider it a rectangular prism.